# Error when adding foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, restrict

I am trying to alter a table in Oracle's **SQL*Plus**
I was able to create a table using the reserved word order using quotes.
I was also able to add a primary key constraint.  When it comes to adding the foreign key I have this error.  I researched about what I could be doing wrong, but I can't find any satisfactory answer. I'll appreciate any help.  THanks!

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE "ORDER"
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK
  3  FOREIGN KEY(C_NO) 
  4  REFERENCES CUSTOMER(C_NO)
  5  ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ON DELETE RESTRICT
          *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: You might consider adopting a convention of plural names for tables, not only because they generally hold multiple items but because you are very much less likely to clash with a reserved word. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not support "RESTRICT"

According to [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm) the options are: (1) omitting the ON DELETE (2) ON DELETE CASCADE and (3) ON DELETE SET NULL.

I believe that omitting the ON DELETE is closest to ON DELETE RESTRICT.

Comment: If you just want to prevent the delete...from the referenced link:  "The foreign key definitions in both variations of this statement omit the ON DELETE clause, causing Oracle to prevent the deletion of a department if any employee works in that department."